# Does PirateBrowser hide my IP address?

Tags: ip-address, tor, piratebrowser

Does [PirateBrowser](http://piratebrowser.com/) hide my IP address?

It uses Tor so the IP should be changed, but when I looked on [What is my IP](http://www.whatismyip.com/), I saw the same address as before.

Is there anybody who can explain it to me?

Comment: You should read up on networking a bit.

Comment: Nothing hides your ip, it's required for internet connections to work. Now if you mean, does Pirate Browser use a proxy system to attempt to change the traffic source ip so the end server doesn't know it, that would be a more important question to ask. Proxy systems are not to be trusted as they can leak the local ip to the remote server.

Comment: @FiascoLabs The point of Tor is anonymous communication. It *was* called "The Onion Router" because *"Onion Routing" refers to the layers of the encryption used. The original data, including its destination, are encrypted and re-encrypted multiple times, and sent through a virtual circuit ... Each relay decrypts a "layer" of encryption to reveal only the next relay in the circuit in order to pass the remaining encrypted data on to it. **The final relay decrypts the last layer of encryption and sends the original data, without revealing or even knowing its sender**, to the destination.*

Comment: @user2607447 - The sole reason this browser exists to get round websites from being blocked by service providers.  It offers no privacy protection beyond that.  The only reason it uses TOR is to accomplish this feat

Comment: `The final relay decrypts the last layer of encryption and sends the original data, without revealing or even knowing its sender, to the destination.`   @ta.speot.is, encryption only matters to the *content* being transferred. For there to be a connection, there has to be a chain of links. Imagine a bunch of students passing a sealed envelope from kid A at one end of the classroom to kid B on the other end. Even if they never look at the letter inside or know the names of the kids on either side of them, there is still a chain from A to B which could potentially be traced from end to end.

Comment: @Synetech But you ignore the last 3 words "To the destination", if kid C only knows that kid B handed the letter to him and was not able to watch the hand-offs from A to B, kid C has no way to trace it back. The point of tor is to have enough hand-offs in enough locations that no one entity could watch all the nodes at once to track it back (which is why tor is normally at least A to B to C to D, if someone wanted to track it back they need to be able to watch all the traffic of B and C which can be hard to do if they are globally separated).

Comment: @ScottChamberlain where did you get kid C from? A is the start, B is the end. There could be any number of kids in the middle, all of which must have contact with the person before and after them in order to receive and pass the message; there *must* be a continuous, unbroken chain between the source and destination for a message to get passed (at least in computer networking). Yes, the point to Tor is to use a bunch of links in different countries and make it as difficult as possible for anyone to track, but that doesn’t mean it’s impossible. Fiasco’s point is that *someone* must see your IP.

Comment: A better analogy is that of rumors. If you want to trace a rumor to its source, you simply pick a person who has heard it, and ask who told them. You then ask that person where they heard it and so on until you find someone who cannot answer because they are the one who made it up. Of course they could lie and make up a source, but that can be detected. The people in the middle could refuse to answer, but that doesn’t guarantee they will (they could be bribed, forced, duplicitous, or tell without realizing it). Either way, there is at least one person who was in contact with the originator.

Comment: @Synetech The point of tor is by using well distributed notes the likelihood that any entity has the resources to follow that trail backwards is extremely small. Under similar logic encryption is pointless as there is some key that could be guessed by brute force to decrypt it, the point is making the key large enough so that no entity would have the resources to brute force it in a reasonable time. Similarly tor, by hopping between nodes in different countries and jusisdictions it makes it too high of requirement for a entity to monitor all the possible links to follow it backwards

Comment: To answer your original question, I renamed kid B to kid C to make my example clearer. Also for your rumor example, lets say you want to follow the rumor backwards. Person A says you need to go to japan and ask person B. Once you get to person B they said person C told them in Nigira, person C said they got it from person D in Swizerland. Now you need to get people/companies/goverments from Japan, Egypt, Nigiria, ans Swizerland to find out the rumor came from me. That level of cooperation even governments may find hard to get/bribe/force.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain, yes, I know that the odds of being able to pull it off is negligible, nobody said it wasn’t. The point is that Fiasco said `Nothing hides your ip` which is true. No matter how difficult you make it to reconstruct the chain, there will always be **someone** who sees your IP address when you make a connection; there’s no way around that.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously, the Pirate Browser doesn't hide your IP address. Your IP address is going to be visible to your local ISP router and every router till you get to your first TOR node. This is the way that IP works. It has to have IP addresses in order to route traffic.

Once on the TOR network, the TOR routing system then practices a whole bunch of security by obscurity tricks and encryption till the traffic leaves the end node on the far side with the return address visible to the remote server hopefully being the one belonging to that TOR node.

So to answer your question, if the browser's TOR configuration is functioning properly and you're actually routing your request to whatismyip through TOR, whatismyip should be reporting the IP address of the last TOR node. Sounds like you need to hit the books and figure out if your Pirate Bay Browser is properly configured so it routes everything through TOR.

After all, the last kerfluffle concerting TOR was that the browser bundle that's supposed to make it easier to use had a security issue that allowed a kiddie porn torrorist to get caught.

**Note:** Per current interviews with the purveyors, Pirate Browser is not intended to provide anonymous or secure internet access. It's mostly there to browse websites with access restrictions that are easily evaded.

Comment: Tor does not use "**security by obscurity**" concept. Tor is an open source project. The principle of Tor is well documented and the implementation is known. There is no obscurity there. Please see what is meant by "[security through obscurity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity)". | You are right that you **cannot hide your IP address** from your ISP but Tor can help you to hide it for example from the destinations you are connecting to through Tor. The other thing is that it is not always successful.